# trying to attach to a process in debug

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

I'm in VS2008 trying to Attach to a process... I can attach fine to the Managed Code, however I get an error when trying to attach to T-SQL it says Access is denied.

How do i resolve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

T-SQL debugging from Visual Studio has a lot of requirements on the server and the client you should review the following the MSDN Documents

[Debugging SQL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zefbf0t6%28v=VS.90%29.aspx)

[Setting Up SQL Debugging](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s4sszxst%28v=VS.90%29.aspx)

[SQL Debugging Setup Errors and Troubleshooting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s7ahaxtd%28v=VS.90%29.aspx)

And in particular since you have Access issues

[SQL Debugging: Security Issues](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s0t6w6kc%28v=VS.90%29.aspx)

[How to: Set SQL Server Permissions for Debugging](http://How%20to%3a%20Set%20SQL%20Server%20Permissions%20for%20Debugging)

Answer (score 1):

Are you debugging locally or on a remote database? If remote, is the user whose context you are debugging in configured as a login in SQL Server?

If it isn't, you will have to run your debugger with an authorized Windows user.